# How i can create extensions to Twilio number using Twilo Studio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-functions

My question is; can i create extensions to Twilio number?

I want to connect each extension to my phone numbers. My goal to send different auto response message to the incoming calls.

Example:

If customer call to number 123, he get message A. And if he call to 345, he will get message.

I want that numbers 123, 345 will be extension to Twilio number.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response, but  I just want to send different SMS
to income calls that their number match my condition I thought about this following flow,I attach an Image , but without success.
My goal is that if person call to number 1234 he will get SMS A and if he call to
number 457 he will get SMS b.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkEhF.png)